# 'react-native-mathjax' height auto adjust not working

Tags: react-native, mathjax, react-native-webview

I am using `react-native-mathjax` for rendering mathematical equations in my react native app but auto-adjust height of webview is not working in `react-native-mathjax` library when I move to the next query.  `react-native-mathjax` takes the previous height to render the next query. how can I adjust view height in my app?

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
 import MathJax from 'react-native-mathjax';

 function Test() {
     return (
              <View>
                  <MathJax
                        html={<p><span class="math-tex">\(\begin{bmatrix} 2 &1 \\[0.3em] 3&4\\[0.3em] \end{bmatrix}\)</span></p>} 
                  />
              </View>
            );
 }
 export default Test;
```

Comment: Can you provide your relevant code?

Comment: @koder613 I am using code provided in `react-native-mathjax` to render my query.

Comment: @koder613 I am using [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mathjax) library to render my query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-native-autoheight-webview` inside `react-native-mathjax` instead of `react-native-webview`. It will automatically adjust height of webview when you move to next query.

```
npm install react-native-autoheight-webview
```